# Groovy - Вставка элемента в список согласно индексу

Tags: коллекции, список, groovy

Есть в Groovy метод удаления элемента из списка по индексу - remove(n)
А что-то подобное insert(n, m) в нём есть? ...

Answer (score 0):

Не все списки можно изменять. Но, например, в `ArrayList`, можно использовать метод `set()` для изменения элемента списка по индексу.

Тем не менее, данный метод будет работать только для значений индекса, не больших чем размер списка.

Подробнее: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)